# Django switch the primary server to secondary along with mysql db

Tags: python, mysql, django, failover

I'm completely new to Django. I have developed a simple web application in Django and hosted it on external server. And that web application uses default mysql database. Now, I want to switch to a secondary server if my primary server goes down. 
Copying and running the same code is not the option. 
Can anyone explain how do I do it along with an example ?

Comment: Meaning, when the webserver goes down (failover of everything) or switching from the same webserver to another instance of MySql when the DB problem occurs?

Comment: This is not a programming but a system management topic. And additionally it is rather complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not a beginner topic or answer but, in a prototypical production-esque deployment with  nginx/apache/django, you can use the **nginx upstream module**

it'll detect when a node is down and won't route requests to the down node, so you'll get the failover behavior you desire out of the box

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream

I googled "nginx upstream module failover" and the second result had some examples: https://serverfault.com/questions/140990/nginx-automatic-failover-load-balancing